# Problema con ASP, Promise, y UseEffect con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, backend, frontend

tengo un problema desde hace tiempo que no entiendo muy bien porque pasa, ya intente de todo mas sin embargo siempre me lo encuentro de una forma u otra, me explico.

Estoy desarrollando una App divida, Front End con React JS y ASP .net en el BackEnd, hasta aquí todo bien.

Diseñe una pagina en el cual lo que busco es, Antes de que se muestren los componentes de mi pagina, quiero hacer 2 llamadas a mi back end para traerme 2 recursos diferentes en formato JSON, ambos recursos de Tipo GET y quiero que se muestre esta información en mis componentes. la información que pido no es nada especial, simples cadenas de texto en JSON como nombre de usuario, identificador, números etc.

Para hacer la llamada a mi backend hago uso de AXIOS, y en este caso hago uso de PROMISE JavaScript en React.

Para ejecutarlo al montar mi componente, hago uso de UseEffect de React, de esta forma ejecuto las 2 llamadas.

No hago uso de Redux, estoy simplemente utilizando SessionStorage y LocalStorage, la logica en mi cabeza es la siguiente:

1. 1.-si no existe el sessionStorage llamado Cliente, voy a ejecutar la funcion GetCliente

   2.- la funcion GetCliente hace una llamadas a la API con AXIOS y me trae la informacion del cliente

   3.- al traerla, convierto el JSON en objeto Javascript con JSON.stringify y de esta forma creo la sessionStorage Cliente.

   4.- Al crerse la sessionStorage Cliente, este se montara sobre un UseState llamado cliente que su estado inicial es null.

   5.- al llenarse el useState cliente, este se pintara sobre la pagina, para pintarlo uso esta notacion cliente?.nombredeusuario,
   para acceder a sus valores y que en caso de que no venga no me
   marque error.

   6.- al crearse la sessionStorage llamada Cliente, si el usuario decide "Refrescar" la pagina ya no tendra que hacer la llamada a la
   API porque ya se encuentra registrado en la pagina, por lo que solo
   tendre que montar la informacion de la sessionStorage en mi
   UseState, de esta forma no sobrecargo de solicitudes mi servidor.

*Ahora aquí viene lo complicado...*

Mi lógica funciona, ya la tengo implementada y si ha funcionado, sin embargo, empiezan a aparecer los siguientes errores.

1.- En ocasiones, cuando entro a la pagina por primera vez, de los 2 recursos que solicito, 1 no llega, tengo 2 funciones, getCliente() este me trae datos de un cliente y getAlmacen() este me trae datos de un almacén.

en ocasiones no llega la información de getCliente pero si la de getAlmacen, y en otras ocasiones no llega la información del getAlmacen pero si la de getCliente.

tengo un botón llamado cerrar sesión que limpia la sessionStorage, cuando intento entrar nuevamente a la pagina no me trae ninguno de los 2 recursos!

Me metí a la pestaña de Red de mi navegador, y en ocasiones veo que mis 2 recursos se ejecutan 2 veces, según lo que se es por UseEffect, que este ejecuta 2 veces mi función, sin embargo en las 2 ocasiones la solicitud de mis 2 recursos se encuentran en estado 304

en ocasiones cuando me meto a la pestaña de red, veo que uno de mis recursos esta en estado 304, y después ese mismo recurso se vuelve a ejecutar por el UseEffect y aparece el estado en 200 señal de que si se logro pero por alguna razón, no se carga en mi SessionStorage! me aparece que se creo la SessionStorage de cliente pero esta vacio!

Ya no se que hacer, e simplificado mucho esta lógica a este punto sin embargo en ocasiones funciona muy bien y en otras ocasiones no funciona!

Ahora si, adjunto todo el código, no se que estoy haciendo mal realmente, incluso mi backend no realiza otras cosas como verificar token o algo por el estilo, simplemente pide el recurso y se lo envía pero no entiendo porque sigue pasando...

***Primero Código de servidor***
este es mi endpoint que trae datos de mi almacen...

```
 [HttpGet("almacen/{dbhandle:int}/{idcaja:int}")]
    public ActionResult<string> getAlmacen(int dbhandle, int idcaja) {
        
        string [] data = ConexionDB.Instance.Obtener_almacen_caja(dbhandle, idcaja);
        var dataconvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        return Ok(dataconvert);
    }
```

este es mi endpoint que trae mis datos de usuario

```
[HttpGet("cliente/{dbhandle:int}")]
    public ActionResult<String> getcliente(int dbhandle) {

        string [] data = ConexionDB.Instance.Obtener_cliente(dbhandle);
        var dataconvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        return Ok(dataconvert);
    }
```

ambos endpoints funcionan, tanto con PostMan lo he probado

Ahora código en React...

```
const VentasMostrador = () => {
//varibles de estado useState
const [cliente, setcliente] = useState(null);
const [almacen, setalmacen] = useState(null);
const [cajero, setcajero] = useState(null);
const [productos, setproductos] = useState([]);
const [cambio, setcambio] = useState(false);
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [productoSeleccionado, setProductoSeleccionado] = useState(null);
const [seriesylotes, setseriesylotes] = useState(null);

if(!sessionStorage.getItem("ID_CAJA")){
    window.location = "/PaginaPrincipal";
}

const getCliente = async () => {
        let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datauser"));
        const promise  = await axios.get("https://localhost:5001/api/ventasmostrador/cliente/"+user.DbHandle);
        if(promise){
            let data = promise.data;
            let infodata = { id: data[0], nombre: data[1], codigo: data[2] };
            sessionStorage.setItem("GET_CLIENTE", JSON.stringify(infodata));
            setcliente(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("GET_CLIENTE")));
        } else {
            console.log("no se pudo cargar los datos de almacen...");
        }
  
};

const getAlmacen = async () => {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datauser"));
    let caja = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ID_CAJA"));
    const promise = await axios.get("https://localhost:5001/api/ventasmostrador/almacen/"+user.DbHandle+"/"+caja);
        if(promise){
            let data = promise.data;
            let infodata = {
                id: data[0],
                caja: data[1],
                idalmacen: data[2],
                nombrealmacen: data[3],
            };
        sessionStorage.setItem("GET_ALMACEN", JSON.stringify(infodata));
        setalmacen(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("GET_ALMACEN")));
    } else {
        console.log("no se pudo cargar los datos de almacen...");
    }       
};
```

ahora para ejecutar estas 2 funciones hago uso de UseEffect.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let datauser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datauser"));
    setcajero(datauser.Nombrecajero);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem("GET_CLIENTE")){
    getCliente();
} else {
    setcliente(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("GET_CLIENTE")));
}
    console.log("cuanto se ejecuta x1...");
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem("GET_ALMACEN")){
    getAlmacen();
    console.log("cuanto se ejecuta x2...");
} else {
    setalmacen(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("GET_ALMACEN")));
}
}, [])
```

Evidencia de toda mi explicacion...

Esta imagen es cuando entre por primera vez a la aplicacion, aqui se ejecuto perfectamente y me salieron los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui la informacion se pinta en mi componente, todo bien y en la pestaña donde se encuentra sessionStorage ambos objetos se crean y se llenan.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui viene el problema, cuando presiono el boton, cerrar sesion, y me salgo de esta pagina, e intento volver a entrar para que se pueda volver a cargar todo, deja de funcionar o 1 recurso, u otro recurso o AMBOS :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si verifico la pestaña de red me aparecen que si me llegaron!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces no se que hacer, se que la explicación es demasiado larga y tediosa pero esto me frustra, no se si esta mal el controlador, useEffect, mi funcion de javascript o la promesa.

Si alguien lee esto porfavor, ayuda :(